# Open incomplete tar.gz file

Tags: zip, tar, tar.gz

I have a backup of my website that seems to have failed in the download and is incomplete. However there is still a lot of stuff in there. Is there a way to extract the archive to retrieve whatever is inside?

I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The gzip in macOS will stop as soon at it hits the premature end of the file, and not provide all of the decompressed data it has extracted so far. However, [pigz](https://github.com/madler/pigz/tree/develop) will provide everything it was able to extract. (That is a recent commit, so you'll need to use the linked develop branch.) You can compile pigz and pipe its output to tar:

```
pigz -d < incomplete.tar.gz | tar -xvf -
```

The last file, very likely cut off in the middle, will be partially extracted with the error:

```
x somefilename: Truncated tar archive
```

All of the files preceding that one will be extracted correctly.

Comment: After some testing and searching I found that any gzip version 1.3.5 or later, from September 30, 2002, will deliver all of the decompressed data from a truncated gzip file. However the default Apple version of gzip that is part of macOS will not (the latest reports itself as `Apple gzip 403.100.6`). Either that is Apple's own implementation of gzip, or it is based on a gzip from before 1.3.5.